# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, powermock

I'm trying to run tests in a legacy `Java` project and I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule
```

The code that is causing the issue is like that:

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

And the `PowerMock` version is `1.5.6`

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

There is not change in the error even when updating to the latest version of `PowerMock` - version 2.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this dependency to get rid of NoClassDefFoundError

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

powermock-module-junit4-1.5.6.jar don't have PowerMockRule class file. so use powermock-module-junit4-rule-2.0.5.jar

refer this [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/powermockrule)

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, this seems to help. 
I had to put this dependency *before* the dependency of _powermock-module-junit4_